# ISAPI Rewrite with instead of mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, isapi, modx

I'm installing Modx on windows with ISAPI Rewrite instead of apache with mod_rewrite?

How do you define the rewrite rules? I'm guessing not with an .htccess file?

any Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [ISAPI_Rewrite 2 documentation](http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/) you need to write the [configuration](http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/#conffile) into the `httpd.ini` file into the `[ISAPI_Rewrite]` section:

```
[ISAPI_Rewrite]

RewriteRule …
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
RewriteRule ^/$    /index.php?REQUEST_URI=index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The global config for [ISAPI_Rewrite 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) is called httpd.conf, and per-site distributed configurations are .htaccess.